# fscanf function doesn't read in c

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I tried to read some data from file and insert it to queue, Insert function works well, and i tried to catch the error with printfs. I saw that in while() line there is error. The data in file forms like that

12345 2

11232 4

22311 4

22231 2

```
void read_file(struct Queue *head){
FILE *fp;
int natid;
int cond;
fp=fopen("patients.txt","r");

    while (fscanf(fp,"%d %d", natid, cond) != EOF)
        insert(head,natid,cond);

fclose(fp);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass *pointers* to where `fscanf()` shall store the values, and check that all expected conversions succeed:

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &natid, &cond) == 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did what you said but now it only reads the first line. Next line which lies under 12345 2 wasn't read by fscanf.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%d %d", natid, cond) != EOF)
```

should be

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%d %d", &natid, &cond) == 2)
```

You need to pass the address of `natid` and `cond` instead of its value as the `%d`s in `fscanf` expects an `int*`, not an `int`. And I've used `== 2` so that the loop breaks in case of `EOF` or invalid data(like characters). Otherwise, if the file contains invalid data, the loop will turn into an infinite loop as `%d` will fail to scan an integer.

---

You should also check if `fopen` was successful. `fopen` returns `NULL` in failure.

Comment: It is successful i checked fopen and did what you said about while loop. It only reads first line now.

Comment: @Y.E.S. , That shouldn't happen. Try replacing `insert(head,natid,cond);` with `printf("%d %d scanned", natid, cond);` to make sure everything is being scanned. I think the problem is in `insert`.